# Function to double a list in Isabelle

Tags: list, isabelle

I would like to define a function in Isabelle/HOL that doubles a list

```
fun double :: "'a list => 'a list" where
...
```

such that `double [x1, x2, ...] = [x1, x1, x2, x2, ...]`

I have tried the following:

```
fun double :: " 'a list ⇒ 'a list" where
"double [] = []" |
"double [x#[l]] = x # x # double [l]"
```

as well as some other definitions. I get the error

> Type unification failed
>
> Type error in application: incompatible operand type

What is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the error message contains some further information. Namely

```
Operator:  double :: 'a list ⇒ 'a list
Operand:   [[x, l]] :: ??'a list list
```

which tells us that `[[x, l]]` is of type `?'a list list`, i.e., a list of lists. As you want to give it as argument to `double`, which expects an argument of type `'a list`, you get the type error.

The origin of the term `[[x, l]]` in the error message is the second line of your definition

```
`double [x # [l]]`
```

where `x#[l]` is printed as the equivalent `[x, l]`.

There are several superfluous brackets in your input. Note that in contrast to informal mathematical text (with *informal* meaning *as on paper* ;)) in Isabelle you cannot use brackets `[`, `]` for explicit nesting. Try the following instead.

```
fun double :: " 'a list ⇒ 'a list"
where
  "double [] = []" |
  "double (x#xs) = x # x # double xs"
```