# Isabelle type unification/inference error

Tags: isabelle

I'm just getting started in Isabelle and I'm getting a type unification error while working through Exercise 3.3 in of [*Concrete Semantics*](http://concrete-semantics.org/):

> Define a substitution function
>
> ```
> subst :: vname ⇒ aexp ⇒ aexp ⇒ aexp
> ```
>
> such that `subst x a e` is the result of replacing every occurrence of variable `x` by `a` in `e`. For example:
>
> ```
> subst ''x'' (N 3) (Plus (V ''x'') (V ''y'')) = Plus (N 3) (V ''y'')
> ```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
theory Scratchpad
imports Main
begin

type_synonym vname = string
type_synonym val = int
type_synonym state = "vname ⇒ val"

datatype aexp = N int | V vname | Plus aexp aexp
    
fun subst :: "vname ⇒ aexp ⇒ aexp ⇒ aexp" where
"subst x (N a) (N e) = (N e)" |
"subst x (N a) (V e) = (if x=e then (N a) else (V e))" |
"subst x (N a) (Plus e1 e2) = Plus(subst(x (N a) e1) subst(x (N a) e2))"

end
```

When the third case in the function definition is commented out, running the test cases

```
value "subst ''x'' (N 3) (N 5)"
value "subst ''x'' (N 3) (V ''x'')"
```

produces `(N 5)` and `(N 3)` respectively, so I know the first two lines are working correctly. Adding the last line results in the error

> Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "_ list"
>
> Type error in application: operator not of function type
>
> Operator:  x :: char list
> Operand:   N a :: aexp

I don't think this is a syntax issue, although I'm not yet completely sure what purposes different types of quotation marks serve (e.g. double quotes vs. two single quotes). From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451675/), I believe that Isabelle is assigning `x` to be a function type on the right side of the line, which is not what I want.

What do the error messages actually mean (specifically and generally), and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question about quotes: Two single quotes are used in Isabelle/HOL (more precisely its *inner syntax*) to denote string literals. That is, by `''abc''` we denote the string containing the three characters `a`, `b`, and `c` (which would again use some special syntax if you had to enter them literally). Double quotes on the other hand, are mostly used to separate Isar statements (*outer syntax*) from terms inside the logic. So while `''...''` is part of the term language, `"..."` is not.

Now for the error message. It tells you that you are trying to use the list `x` (type `_ list`) as a function (type `_ => _`). Why does Isabelle think you want to use `x` as a function? Well, because juxtaposition (i.e., writing terms next to each other, separated by white space) denotes *function application*. Thus `x (N a)` is interpreted as applying a function `x` to an argument `(N a)` (just as `f y` is the application of `f` to the argument `y`). In order to give your definition the correct meaning you have to use parenthesis at the right positions. I guess what you intended in your third clause was:

```
Plus (subst x (N a) e1) (subst x (N a) e2)
```

where we have two occurrences of the function `subst` applied to three arguments. (So it was a syntax issue after all ;).)

Another comment. Your implementation of `subst` could be more general. As is, the second argument of `subst` is always fixed to be some number `a` (because of your usage of the constructor `N`). However, everything should work just as well if you would allow arbitrary expressions of type `aexp`.

Comment: This deserves a vote up, but I don't have 15 reputation yet. I'll have to remember to come back after I do. You're spot-on about the error with the parentheses. I've actually noticed and fixed it in simpler cases, but couldn't see it in this case. Maddening. One follow-up: could you define the phrase "term language"? I'm still hazy at best on the difference between Isabelle, HOL and Isar, and levels of syntax.

Comment: In order to answer your question about the *term language*, I refer to chapter 7 "Inner Syntax - The Term Language" of the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf).